# Как правильно создать hashCode() для сущностей в Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

### Предыстория:

Прочитал в нескольких источниках о том, что `equals()` и `hashcode()` лучше всего перезаписывать, когда работаешь с Hibernate. Раньше мне с этим не приходило встречаться, поэтому хотел бы для себя уточнить/узнать некоторые вещи.

[Item 45: Why Avoid Lombok @EqualsAndHashCode in Entities](https://dzone.com/articles/best-performance-practices-for-hibernate-5-and-spr)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Вот еще один :
[The best way to implement equals, hashCode, and toString with JPA and Hibernate](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-implement-equals-hashcode-and-tostring-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

И вот еще один:
[Ultimate Guide to Implementing equals() and hashCode() with Hibernate](https://thoughts-on-java.org/ultimate-guide-to-implementing-equals-and-hashcode-with-hibernate/)

### Ситуация:

В источниках, приведенных выше, говорилось о том, как создавать `hashCode()` и `equals()`. Ситуацию с `equals()` я понял, а вот с `hashCode()` - не очень.

У меня есть 2, предположим, 2 сущности (независимые друг от друга): `Author` и `Book`.
"Запреты":

- `Object.hash(id)` не подойдет, так как `id` объект получает после отправки hibernate в  БД.
- У моих объектов нету `Business Key` или `@NaturalId`, т.к. поля будут НЕ УНИКАЛЬНЫМИ

Таким образом, остается, как я понял, один вариант решения проблем с `hashCode()` - это "переписывать" данный метод и вручную вставлять число (int). Чаще  всего используют примитивное, нечетное число 31.

### Вопросы:

1 - Как правильно выдавать `hashCode()` нижепредставленным сущностям? (желательно привести пример этих чисел) Имеется ввиду должно ли число удовлетворять каким-нибудь критериям, формуле и т.д.
2 - Могут ли все/несколько сущности, которые созданы в приложении, иметь одинаковые hashCode(), но чем это черевато?

### Update 1:

Вот информация из 3 истоника (см. выше). Что это могло бы значить?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

#### Author.java

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Author {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    private String surname;
}
```

#### Book.java

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Book { 

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    private String title;

    private String edition;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ответ зависит от ответа на вопрос: с точки зрения вашей бизнес логики когда 2 разных `Entity` например `Author` будут считаться идентичными? 3 варианта:

1. Когда их первичные ключи равны. В этом случае `hashCode()` это просто их `id`
2. Когда имя и фамилии авторов идентичны, в этом случае `hashCode()` вычисляется как композиция типа `hash(name+surname)` (где `hash()` более-менее любой алгоритм хэширования типа SHA-256 или даже md5
3. Ни то ни другое. В этом случае при создании записи вам надо генерить некий `businessKey` который будет вычисляться через `Atomic` (правда чем это отличается от `id` - мне сложно понять)

Comment: Ваш 1 вариант не подходит. Как писалось в вопросе, при создании объекта я не задаю первичный ключ, а значит `hashCode()` по первичному ключу нельзя считать, потому что в `hashCode()` будет передано значение `null`. То есть если я создам объект идентичный тому, что в БД, но без первичного ключа, то эти объекты должны иметь одинаковый `hashCode()`, так как по правилам Hibernate, эти объекты гарантировано одинаковы. Таким образом 1 вариант отпадает. Если я  не прав - поправьте)

Comment: 3 вариант не подходит (я не говорю, что не правильно), потому что в вопросе стояла цель избегать BusinessKey (и @NaturalId)

Comment: 2 вариант вроде подходит,  но вот исходя из текста (см. Update 1) это невозможно реализовать. Пример, мы взяли объект `Аuthor`, присвоили его  Объекту `NewAuthor`. Оба объекта сохраняем в БД. Далее  возвращаем их обратно в программу. Замечаем, что они имеют одинаковый `hashCode()`. Далее мы в `NewAuthor` меняем 2 переменные на новые значения. Теперь при сравнении `Author`  с `NewAuthor` объекты будут иметь разный hashCode(), ХОТЯ они должны быть "одинаковыми" , так как это одна и та же сущность. Вот в чем проблема...

Comment: Если я  не прав - поправьте меня

Comment: Я в общем то не говорил какой верный или неверный. Я просто тупо перебрал все возможные варианты. Касательно второго, вы как то определитесь. То есть сначала у вас был автор Лев Толстой, потом вы делаете его копию и переименовываете Льва Толстого в Достоевского и потом жалуетесь, что они не идентичны. Ну ясно же, что Толстой и Достоевский разные сущности - улавливаете? У вас проблема в бизнес-логике, но не в программировании сущностей

Comment: Да, в таком примере они разные. А вот если Александр Пушкин переименовать в Саша Пушкин... Это же по сути одна и таже сущность, но если сравнивать hash у Саша Пушкин и Александр Пушкин, то Hibernate подумает, что это 2 разных объекта.

Comment: Тогда мы опять возвращаемся к варианту 1 - разные первичные ключи = разные авторы. Здесь все в ваших руках, для себя определите правило или найдите `naturalId`

Comment: Я Вас понял! Тогда в своих проектах буду стараться использовать businessKey или naturalID)